# flashplayer binary for fedora 14 - command line usage

Tags: command-line, flash, fedora

Can someone help me locate flashplayer binary on fedora 14. i googled about it all day.
i need to use flashplayer as command line.
thank you very match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is actually called projector or standalone player. 
find the appropriate binary file on this page
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
hope this helps someone